# Why is parallels giving me the error "there is no disk in the drive"?

Tags: macbook-pro, windows, parallels-desktop, dvd, iso

I installed parallels on my macbook pro and i installed windows 7 iso via a DVD.  at first everything looked fine exception now I am now trying to compile an asp.net-mvc app in visual studio and i get this error over and over

[image]

No matter what i click it will eventually progress but this is quite annoying.  The same question [was asked here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/266164) but no good answer was given.

Can someone please explain why devenv.exe would need the ISO dvd to be connected to my laptop at this point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this exact same problem. Windows 7 on Parallels installed via ISO DVD running VS 2010 MVC 4. I can't answer why this happens, but just keep clicking 'Continue', it'll load your site eventually. If you look in the Output window you can see it's making progress.

This only appears to happen the first time you start your project.

Comment: agree . . this problem ultimately just went away :)